# Advanced Power Management in Compaq laptop

Tags: power-management, compaq-laptop

I reinstalled Windows XP in my Compaq Presario V2000, and now the "standby" and "hibernate" options are no longer available. I tried scanning for new hardware, to no avail. In Device Manager, there is no listing for Advanced Power Management. I also checked in the BIOS options, but there is nothing helpful there. What else can I do to get this functionality back?

EDIT: Problem solved. It turns out that the mobo had been replaced, and it was actually a different model that required other drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Did Compaq send you a disk of drivers or system software to install? They may include a driver for power management.

Also, update your BIOS. The updates may include new ACPI routines and/or advertise more compatibility to XP.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any such disk. I tried the HP website but couldn't find any drivers for this particular issue.

Comment: @Dave Did you install the other drivers offered by HP (specifically the motherboard chipset drivers)?

Comment: I tried installing the chipset driver, but got an error that it requires a specific chipset platform and operating system.

Comment: Try updating the BIOS as well (updated my answer to suit). XP may pick up newer BIOS power saving.